# Alternatives for appending a div from a JS object

Tags: javascript, html

I've built my first "real" web app which uses both server-side and client side functions to populate a list of courses a user can register for. Currently, the client receives an Object with the following structure:

**Object**

```
{
  "date": "1/1/2018",
  "time": "14:30",
  "title": "String Title 1",
  "desc": "A long string description with information about the workshop.",
  "cat": "Category 1, Category 2",
  "seats": "20",
  "type": "In Person",
  "location" : "Building A",
  "lock": true,
  "code": "ABCD",
  "hash": "Str1ng",
  "who": "Teachers, Admin"
} ...
```

Then, the client adds `div` elements built from the Object. I'm using `.append()` and inserting object keys at the correct point. It works fine, but I'm feeling like this is a really inefficient and frankly, messy, way to add the content.

**Client script**

```js
var data = JSON.parse(Object);

$("#list").append(
    "<div class='row' id='" + data[j].hash + "'>\
       <span class='time'>" + data[j].time + "</span>\
       <span class='date'>" + data[j].date + ", </span>\
       <input type='checkbox' name='wkshp' value='" + data[j].hash + "'/>\
       <span class='title'>" + data[j].title + "</span>\
       <span class='desc'>" + data[j].desc + "</span>\
       <div class='meta'>
         <span class='loc'>" + data[j].location + "</span>\
         <span class='who'>" + data[j].who + "</span>\
         <span class='cat'>" + data[j].cat + "</span>\
         <span class='type'>" + data[j].type + "</span>\ 
         <span class='seats'>Seats: " + data[j].seats + "</span>\
       </div>\
       <div class='reg-code lock hide'>\
         <h2>Registration Code</h2>\
         <input type='text' name='code' value='' />
       </div>
  </div>"
);
```

What improvements can I make to the Object? Is there a better way to parse the object by the client?

Answer (score 1):

- You could use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to avoid the breaking the strings with `+` and doing `\` to newline. Alternatively, you could use template libraries which are more flexible. [Mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) is a good example.
- Consider using a web framework that does the bulk of the rendering for you. That way, you only have to worry about your data. Web frameworks also do optimizations to avoid re-rendering the entire chunk of HTML, do housekeeping, etc.

Other than that, there's not much to review.